# Can we change the migration banner?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, status-completed, migration

Now that the title prompt for new questions has been changed from

> What's your creation and solving of puzzles question? Be specific.

to

> What's your puzzle or your puzzle-related question? Be specific.

... how about the banner for questions migrated from here to other Stack Exchange sites? Currently it looks like this:

[image: migration banner]

After major changes in the direction of the site since private beta, a "site for those who study the creation and solving of puzzles" is no longer an apt description. **What do we want this banner to say instead?**

Feel free to post suggestions as answers to be voted on, as in the previous thread.

---

And of course a couple of practical issues:

- ***can* this be changed?** (I assume it can, in the same way as the title prompt)
- **has it already been changed in line with the change in title prompt?** (I hope not, since that change was from "creation and solving of puzzles" to "puzzle or your puzzle-related", and *"This question came from our site for those who study the puzzle or your puzzle-related"* doesn't sound good!)

Comment: Just wondering, to whom does the text there not apply? It still seems totally acceptable to me, but I could easily be missing something.

Comment: @Emrakul Hmm. Would you say creating and solving puzzles counts as *studying* the creation and solving of puzzles? What we're doing is a bit more proactive than study, IMO. Maybe "**our site for experts in the creation and solving of puzzles**" would be a good alternative? (I don't know whether it has to fit "those who study" in the same way as the title prompt had to be "What's your __ question?")

Comment: Edit: scratch that, I've just found out. Worldbuilding is apparently "our site for writers/artists using science, geography and culture to construct imaginary worlds and settings". Seems like there's a fair bit of flexibility here.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say it does. Above all, I think we *are* studying puzzle creation: figuring out what works and what doesn't has been key to the site's development. I honestly think we're a community about learning to do what we do better, and enjoying ourselves while we do so.

Comment: @Emrakul While I support rand's request, I absolutely *love* your comment! The first time I've seen a mod posting to be of exactly my opinion about the purpose of this site. (*learning* how to create/solve puzzles)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I think the current text is out of place for a mostly challenge-based site. I propose:

> This question came from our site for those who create, solve, and
>   study puzzles.

Comment: This has now been implemented - see Emrakul's answer.

Answer (score 2):

This change has been implemented in the next build and should show up shortly around the network.

There is an important note, though: **This string is used in a number of places around the network.** It's not possible, for instance, to separate the string in migration banner from the string on the general Stack Exchange site list.

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> (these will change, too)

Since hunting down all the places this is used is liable to be an ineffective and incomplete venture, we've gone ahead and asked SE the change anyway. Feel free to let us know if it looks or sounds weird somewhere around the site or the network.

Comment: Thanks for the update and extra info! When you say "this change", is it the wording suggested by @xnor in his answer?

Comment: @rand Yep, that wording will be used.

Answer (score 0):

### Keep it simple and consistent

swap

"site for those who study the creation and solving of puzzles"

for

"site for puzzles and puzzle-related questions"

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it may have to fit the pattern "site for [group of people]". All the migration banners I've seen are in this form.

Comment: @randal'thor "site for puzzled people" ?

Comment: Nice one! :-D But we're actually _less_ a site for puzzled people (people who have problems that they need help with) than most SEs!

Comment: People come here without questions and leave with.  maybe "site for people looking to be  puzzled" ?

Comment: @randal'thor A site for *bepuzzled* people maybe? (I made the word)